# How do I sum all integers in a list multiplied by their indexes?

Tags: python, list, indexing, sum, integer

The goal is to return the sum of all items in a list, where each item is multiplied by its index.

My code works for a few test cases; however, it does not work for others. Why not?

```
def index_multiplier(lst):
    total = 0
    if len(lst) >= 1:
        for num in lst:
            x = num*(lst.index(num))
            total += x
        return total
    else:
        return 0
```

The first test case that doesn't work:
Test.assert_equals(index_multiplier([4, 4, 2, 2, -4]), -2)

My code returns -8

Answer (score 2):

`.index` will always return in the index of the first occurence of the element. So `lst.index(num)` will return `0` for both the first and second `4` in your list.

Instead use `enumerate(lst)` to keep track of the index while you loop through the list.

```
def index_multiplier(lst):
    total = 0
    if len(lst) >= 1:
        for i, num in enumerate(lst):
            x = num * i
            total += x
        return total
    else:
        return 0
        
print(index_multiplier([4, 4, 2, 2, -4])) # this will print -2.
```

If you dont want to use `enumerate` for whatever reason, you could create you own counter like so:

```
def index_multiplier(lst):
    total = 0
    if len(lst) >= 1:
        i = 0
        for num in lst:
            x = num * i
            total += x
            i += 1
        return total
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: so enumerate() takes two iterables and assigns a unique number to every item in the list?

Comment: enumerate takes 1 iterable, and returns 2 values. The first is the index, and the 2nd is the value at that index. If you dont want to use enumerate, I've added another example in my post.

Comment: aren't both "i" and "num" iterables?

Comment: @Mythic-ctrl Nah. An iterable is something you can iterate, i.e loop over. In our case the iterable is `lst`, since you are looping over it. `i` and `num` are just variables we use to store the information about where we are in the iterable `lst`. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't many opportunities to pitch [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), so I'll just mention this as a succinct and interesting way to do this. `starmap` will multiply the index/value pairs from `enumerate()` using [`operator.mul()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul), then you `sum()` that:

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import starmap

l  = [4, 4, 2, 2, -4]
sum(starmap(mul, enumerate(l)))
# -2
```

Answer (score 2):

why not just a simple list comprehension?

```
x = [4, 4, 2, 2, -4]
out = sum([i*y for i,y in enumerate(x)])
```

output:

```
-2
```

edit - can be used without square brackets:

```
out = sum(i*y for i,y in enumerate(x))
```

Comment: +1 This is probably the canonical way to do this. One note: you can remove the `[ ]` to make a generator that avoids creating a new list.